# Masterserver.UnregisterHost?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming

I am trying to get old games out of `Masterserver.PollHostData()`. When a game is finished an I run the following script the client still gets the game from `PollHostData()`.

```
    if(Network.isClient)
    {
        if (Network.connections.Length == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Disconnecting from server");             
            Network.CloseConnection(Network.connections[0], true);
            MasterServer.UnregisterHost(); //Tried UnregisterHost() first as well.
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not connected to server");
        }
    }
    else if (Network.isServer)
    {
        if (Network.connections.Length > 0)
        {
            Network.Disconnect(1000); 
            MasterServer.UnregisterHost(); //Tried UnregisterHost() first as well.
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No clients connected.");
            Network.Disconnect(0);
            MasterServer.UnregisterHost(); //Tried UnregisterHost() first as 
        }
    }
```

However if the client restarts the game I won't get the `HostData` of the previous game anymore. I have tried clearing hostData before polling for it again but without success. The player who created the server does not get the game, which is strange since I clear my `hostData` array before assigning it again.

I found some old posts saying `UnregisterHost` is not working, if so what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i don't understand why

```
MasterServer.UnregisterHost(); //Tried UnregisterHost() first as well.
```

is here. Because master server  has server information,not client information.

```
if(Network.isClient)
    {
        if (Network.connections.Length == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Disconnecting from server");             
            Network.CloseConnection(Network.connections[0], true);
            MasterServer.UnregisterHost(); //Why?
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not connected to server");
        }
    }
```

Solution is:

On Client side, you need to call `MasterServer.ClearHostList();` before request list from MasterServer.

Comment: It is the other way around. Firstly, it is there because i was getting desperate for getting the servers out of the master server. The problem is: When i run `MasterServer.UnregisterHost()` on client or server or anywhere and refresh the list on the client that was in that game the server still shows up. So in the code above where i `UnregisterHost` i still get that server displayed even when the server `Unregisterd.

Comment: Main problem is UnregisterHost is server side job. "Does nothing if the server is not registered or has already unregistered." so it is meanless. [UnityDocs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MasterServer.UnregisterHost.html)

Comment: I first register a game. When game is over I call `MasterServer.UnregisterHost()` on server. When clients in that game press a button to return to the menu and poll for new servers this server still shows up. When clients restart app it does not show up and when the player who created the server goes back to the menu and refreshes it does not show up either.

Comment: When the client tries to access that server, that has just been polled he cannot connect `The connection request to xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx failed. Are you sure the server can be connected to?` obviously... but why does it show up?

Comment: I understood your problem now. please try this path

1. MasterServer.UnregisterHost // server side

2. MasterServer.ClearHostList; //client side

3. MasterServer.RequestHostList //client side

4. MasterServer.PollHostList //client side

if the problem still occurs maybe synchronization problem here. wait some time and press replay.

Comment: I had to add `ClearHostList` just before gathering HostInformation again. Could you edit your answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Ok,I changed. Thank you :)